# how to display records in dataprovider of yii?

Tags: datagridview, yii, dataprovider

I want to use this query in dataprovider

```
select user.username ,company_user.* from user left join company_user on company_user.user_id=user.id where company_user.company_id=".$id
```

how to write in CActiveDataProvider

plz help me
Thank in advance...

I have 3 tables
**company_user**->id,company_id,user_id,first_name,last_name
**company**->id,name_of_company
**user**->id,username,password

I want all records from **company_user** + username from **user**

Thanks in advance...:)

i want list in CGridView

in my user model I have written this type of relations

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'company_user'          =>array(self::HAS_ONE,'CompanyUser','user_id','select' =>array('first_name','status'),
                                            'with'=>array('company'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'company_id','joinType' => 'INNER JOIN')),
                                    ),
            'company_user_rel_only' =>array(self::HAS_ONE,'CompanyUser','user_id','select' =>array('first_name', 'last_name')),
            
    }
```

Comment: If you created models with Gii, you should already have relations set up. Try using them instead.

Comment: hello @Örs, now plz say how to use this relation?

Answer (score 2):

With Yii, you should use the model approach, something like this should work:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = 'user';
$criteria->compare('company_id', $id); //if error due to similar column name change it to t.company_id
$dataProvider =  new CActiveDataProvider('CompanyUser', array(
                     'criteria' => $criteria,
                 ));
```

I'll asume that relation's name between CompanyUser and User is user, if not, change the with attribute to the correct name. Also, this will give objects of the type CompanyUser, if you wanna access to the user atributes, access them with  **->user->username**